# How can I use layer.Timedistributed to process two input in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

My Keras version is 2.2.5, tensorflow is 1.15, python is 3.6.

Now, I want to convert RetinaNet to a timedistributed network to process some 3d data, but I fing that when I use `keras.layter.Timedistributed`, I find it can't process the layer which has two inputs, such as:
`layers.UpsampleLike(name='P5_upsampled')([P5, C4])`
The shape of the `P5` is`(?, ?, x, y, 256)`, the shape of the `C4` is `(?, ?, a, b, 1024)`. Because the `x,y` is different with `a,b` and the `P5` need to be added with the `C4`, so I need to resize the image of the `P5`. That is what `layer.UpsamleLike()` dose. The code I use is like this:

```py
P5 = keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Conv2D(feature_size, kernel_size=1, strides=1, padding='same'), name='C5_reduced')(C5)
P5_upsampled = keras.layers.TimeDistributed(layers.UpsampleLike(), name='P5_upsampled')([P5, C4])
```

and the `layer.UpsampleLike` is:

```py
class UpsampleLike(keras.layers.Layer):
    """ Keras layer for upsampling a Tensor to be the same shape as another Tensor.
    """

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        source, target = inputs
        target_shape = keras.backend.shape(target)
        if keras.backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
            source = backend.transpose(source, (0, 2, 3, 1))
            output = backend.resize_images(source, (target_shape[2], target_shape[3]), method='nearest')
            output = backend.transpose(output, (0, 3, 1, 2))
            return output
        else:
            return tensorflow.compat.v1.image.resize_images(source, (target_shape[1], target_shape[2]), method=tensorflow.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)
```

I think the Timedistributed layer is unstack the inputs and inputs them, so I want Timedistributed process two inputs dividly and input them into `layer.UpsampleLike`, how can I do it?

Comment: What is the shape of the two inputs P5 and C4? Is it possible to apply TimeDistributed to each tensor individually? Can you share your model layers or the corresponding code indicating where or how you need the timedistributed wrapper?

Comment: I add my code and explain more

Answer (score 0):

if I understood the problem correctly, here is a possible solution to manage multiple inputs with different shapes:

```
input_a = Input(shape=(?, ?, x, y, 256))
input_b = Input(shape=(?, ?, a, b, 1024))

x = Dense(256)(input_a)
x = Dense(256)(x)
x = Model(inputs=input_a, outputs=x)

y = Dense(256)(input_b)
y = Dense(256)(y)
y = Model(inputs=input_b, outputs=y)

# combine the output of the two branches
combined = concatenate([x.output, y.output])
z = Dense(256)(combined)
z = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(z)

model = Model(inputs=[x.input, y.input], outputs=z)
```

Layers, output and inputs are examples... You can change them with whatever you need.